# @rem '; what does this line do in pl2bat/perl2bat?

Tags: perl, batch-file

The code excerpts below are from typical pl2bat files.
For those pl2bat/perl2bat files, I can understand what the "goto" and "#!" lines do .

But what about the two characters `';` in that `@rem ';` line?

Is there any special purpose to put the two characters `';` ?

`;` is the perl line seperator.

But that line makes no sense because `perl -x` already ensures that it ignores lines before the `#!perl` line

```
perl -x -S %0 %*
goto endofperl
@rem ';
#! perl
#line 29
```

Comment: `rem` is a command to remark or comment a line in a batch file. The line will be parsed at run time, but do nothing. The preceding `@` tells the parser not to output the command when it is read. So if `echo` is not turned `off` at the time that line is reached, you will not see it parsed in the output file or device. In the context of what you've submitted, I can see no obvious reason for the two character string `';` however.

Comment: My best guess would be that this is a hybrid type file which can be read by both the perl and batch parsers, and that prior to the batch file code there is another line beginning with `@rem` and followed by another `'` character. My assumption is that the perl parser will ignore all code written between `'` and `';` and that `@rem` is a non-executing/harmless command in perl, as it is in batch.

Comment: I  know well both batch and perl syntax here, only what is  the purpose of those to characters '; ?

Comment: Re "*hybrid type file*", "[polyglot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing))" is the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It closes an earlier quote.

---

The `pl2bat` utility transforms

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.14;
say "Hi";
```

into

```perl
@rem = '--*-Perl-*--
@set "ErrorLevel="
@if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" @goto WinNT
@perl -x -S "%0" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
@set ErrorLevel=%ErrorLevel%
@goto endofperl
:WinNT
@perl -x -S %0 %*
@set ErrorLevel=%ErrorLevel%
@if NOT "%COMSPEC%" == "%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe" @goto endofperl
@if %ErrorLevel% == 9009 @echo You do not have Perl in your PATH.
@goto endofperl
@rem ';
#!/usr/bin/perl
#line 16
use v5.14;
say "Hi";
__END__
:endofperl
@set "ErrorLevel=" & @goto _undefined_label_ 2>NUL || @"%COMSPEC%" /d/c @exit %ErrorLevel%
```

If executed as a batch file, it will end up executing `perl -x -S %0 %*`, which will tell Perl to start executing at the `#!` line.

But passing the batch file directly to Perl works as well because it sees

```perl
@rem = '...';
#!/usr/bin/perl
#line 16
use v5.14;
say "Hi";
__END__
```

Comment: It doesn't. It adds `@rem = '` and `';`, and I explained why.

Comment: Thank you. And yes, I just read carefully through your answer. And I see the line that I questioned is actually echoing the earlier line in the file @rem = '--*-Perl-*--,  such that the two single quotes matched.